# how useful is to create an osgi utility bundle

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to develop a simple application using OSGi framework. My question involves an "utility bundle" available in the framework: let me explain with a pretty verbose example. At the moment I'm trying to build an event my bundle will send.

From what I understood, what i need is to do something like the following ([event admin felix](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-event-admin.html)):

```
public void reportGenerated(Report report, BundleContext context)
    {
        ServiceReference ref = context.getServiceReference(EventAdmin.class.getName());
        if (ref != null)
        {
            EventAdmin eventAdmin = (EventAdmin) context.getService(ref);

            Dictionary properties = new Hashtable();
            properties.put("title", report.getTitle());
            properties.put("path" , report.getAbsolutePath());
            properties.put("time", System.currentTimeMillis());

            Event reportGeneratedEvent = new Event("com/acme/reportgenerator/GENERATED", properties);

            eventAdmin.sendEvent(reportGeneratedEvent);
        }
    }
```

Now, since an OSGi application may have lots of bundles, I thought to create a subclass of Event for every bundle (eg. I have a bundle named "BundleExample"? Inside it's exported classes there will be a "BundleExampleEvent"). I **know this doesn't add any information since you can know which event you received by looking at "topic", but please bear with me for the moment**.

Now, the `Event` constructor needs a topic and a `Map<String, Object>`. However, to "simplify" the event constructor, I would like to have only the topic and the list of parameters to put inside the map. For example here's what might be a BundleExampleEvent class:

```
public class BundleExampleEvent extends Event{

    private int importantVariable;

    public BundleExampleEvent(String topic, int importantVariable) {
        super(topic, Utils.toMap("importantVariable", importantVariable));
        //here toMap is static
    }

    public int getImportantVariable() {
        return this.importantVariable;
    }   
}
```

Ok, please note the `Utils.toMap`: it's a function that allows you to convert a sequence of `String, Object` into a `Map`. Ok, now `Utils` is an example of a utility class (stupid, useless but a utility class nonetheless). **In the spirit of OSGi I want to make this utility class a bundle as well**: my thought would be to start this Utils bundle at framework boot and then whenever I need one of its utility I want to fetch a reference via `@Reference` annotation.

This can work greatly in any bundle interface implementation, like this:

```
@Component
public class BundleExampleImpl implements BundleExample {
   @Reference
   private Utils utils;

   @Override
   public String sayHello() {
      return this.utils.fetchHello();
      //another useless utility function, but hopefully it conveys what i'm trying to do
   }
}
```

But what about other classes (i.e. called by BundleExampleImpl during its work)? For example what about the `BundleExampleEvent`? I need to call it from `sayHello` method and I want to use this utility also inside that class in order to compute the Map! In the previous example i used a static function, but I would like to use the reference of `Utils` OSGi gave me.

**Of course I could add a parameter inside the constructor of `BundleExampleEvent` in order to satisfy the link** but I rather not to do it because it's pretty silly that something would depend on an "utility class"; my question are:

1. Is this the only method available if I want a "utility bundle"?
2. Or can I do something weird like adding a reference of Utils also in my `BundleExampleEvent`; i.e. something like this:

   ```
   public class BundleExampleEvent extends Event{
       @Reference
       private Utils utils;
       private int importantVariable;

       public BundleExampleEvent(String topic, int importantVariable) {
           super(topic, Utils.toMap("importantVariable", importantVariable));
           //here toMap is static
       }

       public int getImportantVariable() {
           return this.importantVariable;
       }   
   }
   ```
3. Or maybe the whole idea of having an "utility bundle" is just pure trash?

Thanks for any reply. Hope I could convey my problem in the clearest way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any point in Utils being a service. Things should only be a service if they can conceivably have multiple implementations. In your case, the consumer of the Util functionality only ever wants a single implementation... the implementation **is** the contract.

I don't even think the utils code should be in a bundle. Just make it into a library that is statically linked into the bundles that need it.

Comment: Static linking is a good concept but I think it is not well understood by users. It also took me a while to understand how and where to use it. Maybe worth a blog entry if you do not already have one :-)

Comment: That is what I hoped for :-) Thanks

Comment: After some thought I totally agree with you: using a bundle to contain the utility is useless since the implementation is the contract. There is only one thing I am unsure about. With static linking (via Conditional-Package), if I need to update the utility class (maybe because I added a new utility method), can I uninstall every bundle using such utility, change physically the utility jar and reinstall everything? What I'm trying to do is to avoid the restart of the whole application (although I'm aware that if the utility class is used throughout all the bundles, both solutions are equal)

Comment: It depends on the nature of change you're talking about. If you have added a feature then there is no need to update every bundle, just the ones that need the new feature. If it's a critical bugfix or security update then yes you need to update every bundle using it. You don't have to restart the whole app though -- the Bundle.update() method works in milliseconds.

Comment: I'll accept your answer because, if other people see this question, yours contains exactly why creating an utility bundle is useless (citing you "the implementation is the contract"). Adding the static linking is also a good reference for future noob developers like me

Comment: Just an addendum for you Neil: Can you please edit your answer to add a Conditional-Package usage for adding utility class? some thing like: <Conditional-Package>com.my-awesome-project.utils.*</Conditional-Package>? In this way future developers have also a reference on how to perform such static linking!

Comment: @NeilBartlett are your blogs still available? The links seem to now redirect to a Thai real estate site.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the Utils utils would be an OSGi service. Then you want to use this service inside an object that is not a service like BundleExampleEvent.

What you could do is to create a service that creates BundleExampleEvent instances and feeds it with an OSGi service. Kind of like a factory as a service. The problem with this is that services in OSGi are dynamic. If the service needed by the BundleExampleEvent instance goes away then the object would have to be discarded. So this only works for short lived objects.

In the eventadmin example a different solution would be to not use a special event class but instead create a service that has a method to send such an event. Then all the magic would happen inside this method and the result would be an event without further logic. You could also inject EventAdmin into that service using DS.
This works very well in OSGI but has the disadvantage of the anemic domain model (http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).

I am not sure which variant to prefer.

Comment: from what I understood in order to avoid putting the reference of Utils inside the constructor I need to create another service for that sole purpose. Sounds like a lot of code for pretty much nothing. I think my best option here is to just pass the Utils instance in the constructor or give up on the Utils bundle. In your opinion, which one is the most OSGi-friendly option? I'm OSGi n00bie so I'm unsure about the optimal solution. Thanks!

Comment: If your Utils class does not need a service or has static methods then simply use it like in plain java. You do not need to inject it. So you can call such methods inside your event object without any contructor injection. 
Btw. I am not sure if using a specialized Event class is recommended. At least I never saw it.

Comment: I think specializing Event is infact useless... the only thing you get from specializing them is some getter and setter. About the utility class... I'm unsure because if there is bug inside the utility class the only way to solve it is to manually stop the framework, update the class and then relaunch it; if it was an OSGi injected bundle I could have just update the bundle itlself. I think here we're in a easycoding-robustness tradeoff scenario. Have you already seen utility class bundles? Just to understand if my solution has already been used by someone else!

Comment: There are lots of cases where classes are used directly in OSGi. All simple libraries work this way. As long as your class does not need configuration or other services it is no problem to simply instantiate it with new or uses static methods.

Beware of classes or packages named Util though. They tend to attract all kind of methods. So they have low cohesion and couple classes indirectly that should not be related.

About updates at runtime. This can still work but you will have to refresh and restart all bundles using the classes. Runtime updates are not really that important though.

Comment: I thought runtime updates were essential if you want to keep high availability of you application... am I wrong? When thinking about OSGi, I was sure that modularity and dynamic updates were the strong points of the framework... Or I just have a naive view?